# AngularJS - Tabs and ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I use AngularJS. I have these tabs.

index.html

```
 <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
   </ul>

 <div id="tabs-1">
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="leftcol">
        <div ng-model="models" ng-repeat = "model in models">
          {{model.name}}, {{model.town}}
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">

  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the controller

script.js

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
       $scope.models =
      [ {   name: 'model1', town: 'London'}, {   name: 'model2', town: 'London'}, { name: 'model3', town: 'Paris'}, {   name: 'model4', town: 'Paris'}]; 
}
```

what I would like to do is to use the same list of models and display models from London in tab 1 and model of Paris in tab 2. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a filter:

```
<div ng-model="models" ng-repeat = "model in models | filter: { town: 'London' }">
     {{model.name}}, {{model.town}}
</div>
```

This will only repeat items from London.